# Listing Adjectives - A, thus B yet C

Tags: grammar

Let me give an example sentence:

- The boy is young, thus bold yet imprudent.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: What exactly is it that troubles you about its grammar? Why do you suspect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is gramatically correct, however it is not syntactically well constructed and therefore jars. The presence of "yet" declares that the following adjective is somewhat opposite in meaning to the prior adjective, for example

> The boy is young, thus bold yet overly sensitve

In your example "bold" and "imprudent" can be said to be very similar in meaning (depending on context of course). In that cicumstance you would use the word "and" as in

> The boy is young, thus bold *and* imprudent